# Make clean task before any other

Tags: java, gradle, maven-publish

I would like to make releaseBuild task that will execute clean task before building project.

I have prepared script that works great to do clean before releaseBuild task, not cleaning just before finishing thanks to `jar.mustRunAfter(clean)`.

However, I would like also to have possibility to execute publishToMavenLocal task that will be done only after releaseBuild finish successfully (so cleaning and building). Then there is problem.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task releaseBuild {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    // generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication.mustRunAfter(clean)
    jar.mustRunAfter(clean)
    releaseBuild.dependsOn(clean, build)
}

publishToMavenLocal.dependsOn(releaseBuild)

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            pom {
                from components.java
                packaging 'jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`gradle releaseBuild` works well.
`gradle publishToMavenLocal` shows the error:

```
> Task :generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
> Task :clean
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar
> Task :publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: __path__\build\publications\mavenJava\pom-default.xml (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki -- File not found)
```

The clean is after generating pom file.

When I uncomment line with `generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication.mustRunAfter(clean)`, I've got error:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication' for task ':releaseBuild' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add at **the end** of your script.

```
publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal.mustRunAfter(clean)
```

2. There is a [task-tree](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.dorongold.task-tree) plugin which is very helpful in such situations.
3. It is handy to distinguish between Configuration and Execution phases of Gradle build when fine-tuning tasks configuration. It will help if you read about [Build Lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).
4. Adding dependencies to the `clean` task usually gives more headache than benefit. Consider adding only "soft" dependencies like `mustRunAfter` and add `clean` task explicitly to your command line:

```
gradle clean releaseBuild publishToMavenLocal
```